# Empty div and clickable url

Tags: html, css, url

I have a background with two urls, one showing the regular state and the hover state.  The div is empty and the width and height are set to 50px.  I added padding to see if that would help, it did not.

```
<div class="container_12 clearfix">
<div class="grid_12">
<p id="footer-center">
<a href="#top" class="top-btn" id="back-to-top"><div class="hover-btn"></div><!--<img src="images/back-to-top-a.png" class="a">--></a>
</p>
</div> <!-- end grid_4-->
</div> <!-- end container_12 -->


.hover-btn{
display:block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
margin-left:50%;
}

.hover-btn{
background:url(../images/back-to-top-a.png) no-repeat center
center;
}

.hover-btn:hover{
background:url(../images/back-to-top-b.png) no-repeat center center, url(../images/back-to-top-a.png) no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: what exactly is your query?

Comment: Working Code thanks to Saeed Ludeen                                                          
<a href="#top" class="top-btn" id="back-to-top"><img src="images/back-to-top-a.png" class="hover-btn"></a>

Comment: Working Code thanks to Saeed Ludeen                                                          .hover-btn{
 display:block;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 margin-left:50%;
}
.hover-btn:hover{
 background:url(../images/back-to-top-b.png) no-repeat center center;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replacing the hover-btn div with an img tag will show your first image and then the second on hover.

```
<img src="" class="hover-btn">
```